# If fat cell number stays the same after adulthood, how can adults gain huge amounts of weight?

Tags: weight, body-fat

A [lot of research](http://www.nature.com/news/2008/080505/full/news.2008.800.html) indicates that after the start of adulthood, the number of adipocytes in the body remains basically constant for the remainder of one's life. And yet, it is still possible for a 160lb adult male to triple his or her body weight through fat gain. Considering existing adipocytes can only store so much additional fat through expansion, how is this possible?

Is it theoretically possible then to place a cap on weight gain in adulthood by minimizing weight throughout childhood, or removing adipose tissue, so that there simply are not enough cells to store more than a certain amount of fat?